# assign folder name on runtime in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans, file-io

```
   <%
        String s=request.getParameter("text1");  //text1 is textbox
        java.io.File file = new File("c:/jk");  //location is c: 
   %>

   <%
     if (!file.exists()) //check if file exists

      file.mkdirs();
   else
       out.println("the file exists");           
    %><br/>
```

how can i assign name of that folder on run time instead of jk..

that means i gave a random name in `text1` and folder should be saved with that random name..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 String folderName="folderName" //get this at run time
 new File("C:/" + folderName);
```

this is the way you can.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do it by concatenating a variable in file so: `new File("c:/" + varName)`